# Realistically could someone like the green goblin just wearing street cloths, no glider, defend himself with just hand to hand against 30 people

Tags: internal-consistency, science-fiction

All the questions about super strength seem to be about either robots or people like superman. 
I also wonder how useful such soldiers would be in the real world if they were sane and loyal. Would thousands of such soldiers make a difference? 
If they were just walking around as civilians and people attack them what would realistically happen assuming they are unarmed and the attackers might be armed. Like the green goblin means same strength, same durability same reflexes etc. Imagine someone else going through the same process so the same results but without the insanity. The soldiers would have the same armor the same glider etc. Thousands would be what ever the government would deem cost effective. If the soldiers weren't useful then 1000 if the soldiers were very useful or high demand then 10,000+. It would be a cost/benefit based on needs. Civilians would have normal human strength for the question although if superheros or supervillians existed the soldiers could be used against them. The question I wonder is if unarmed and no armor would someone who was sane who had the same stats as Marvel's Green Goblin be able to defend themselves against a large group of normal street thugs.

Comment: This probably wants some clarification. What does "like the green goblin" mean in this context?

Comment: "*I also wonder how useful such soldiers would be in the real world if they were sane and loyal.*" what soldiers? What are the capabilities they have. "*Would thousands of such soldiers make a difference?*" a difference in what? And how many thousands? "*If they were just walking around as civilians and people attack them what would realistically happen assuming they are unarmed and the attackers might be armed.*" again - what are the soldiers? Who attacks them? What are the attackers armed with? What sort of setting even is this?

Comment: Relative firepower and surprise (and other classic [Jominian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine-Henri_Jomini) factors), not relative physical strength, governs outcome of most small infantry engagements. A soldier needs strength, stamina, and speed to carry that firepower to the engagement in time to be effective, to use that firepower during the engagement, and to evacuate their equipment and casualties afterward.

Comment: What it comes down to is how to put numbers on it. When you say "like the Green Goblin", do you mean "can bench-press a bus and survive getting hit by a train"? And even then, all the little details about musculature and mechanics matter. After all, Knights in full plate were basically super soldiers, but could still be knocked over, pinned and whacked in the head.

Comment: @VLAZ i'm sure that he means green goblin soldiers.

Comment: @StarfishPrime i'm pretty sure he also means the green goblin from spiderman, a man with, i think, super strength, and is green. its like a hulk virus chemical thing, that occasionally takes control, and gives the user hallucinations, and delusions, and essentially makes them schizophrenic as fuck and occasionally gives them violent rages as "a green goblin"

Comment: @michaelgriffin I'm also sure of that but I've no idea what a green goblin soldier is supposed to be capable of. Nor do I know who would be attacking the soldiers, with what weapons, nor why the number of soldiers will be making a difference, nor *what* that difference would be made *to*. I'd say the question is not clear at all.

Comment: @VLAZ that's fair. I'm sure he means the green goblins fighting the civilians, but who knows. and also yeah he has to specify the number of them. 2000? 3000? 14000? and I'm sure what he means is "would thousands(again, unclear number) of green goblin soldiers make a difference as opposed to just one" which I would say yes. 1 green goblin can be nuked. if it was thousands, then some of them might survive and thus kill the rest of the world. if it was a loyal army, then it would be a near-unstoppable force that everyone would be against.

Comment: OP needs to specify which version of the Green Goblin they're talking about. Depictions of the Green Goblin have varied /widely/ in expressed strength and fighting capability in the past fifty years or so. Some of them are just Norman Osborne (or Harry, or someone else) with a touch of madness and a freaky suit. Some of them are hulking mutated monsters born of  attempts to recreate super-soldier serum.

Comment: The trouble with this sort of analysis is that the stories you're referring to are fairy tales not hard science, so their abilities are entirely dependent on the requirements of the story at that moment.

Answer (score 1):

What I understood is can someone with above human strength and reflexes win in a fight against a larger group of humans who happen to be armed and a similar group that is unharmed. 
So here we go.

- General rules of combat is it's all about the context.
- Unarmed. Definitely. If all your soldier needs just a punch and a person is out, dead or badly hurt, then basic strategy of letting an attacker come at a time and then a single punch should suffice. They also won't fear being attacked and even a couple of attackers would cause little damage giving the whole super strength thing. People can actually take a lot of damage.
- Armed. Well. Depends on the reflex and the context. For example if they are fast enough to simply dodge every single cut or hit then obviously you can't touch them or at least with basic intelligence they can avoid too much damage.
- If their speed is anything below absolute super fast then once you factor in melee weapons I'd say they need to be very careful. In the former example a punch landing on the soldier means nothing. But here a cut artery or a lead pipe to the head is big trouble.
- In the case of a group attack it becomes a matter of funneling in the attackers. Isolate targets and force them to come at you one or two at a time. But if they get the soldier in a circle or in a situation were he/she can't react to two attacks from two different directions then it's done. They don't have to be suicidal, small cuts and bruises overtime will bleed the super soldier dry.
- Firearms are obviously a game changer. You can't just stomach them and you can't dodge them and only in badly made actions scenes do the shooters attack from spitting distance. Even a 9mm pistol can kill a person at more than a 100 meters so not exactly a lot of room to wiggle.
- And lastly I'll assume that the rest of the paragraph are just to
  acquaint us with the world. I mean I can talk a lot about "super"
  soldiers but generally speaking they are just a bad idea.